# C# LINQ Check sum of columns in the same query

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to check if the sum of PREM_A or PREM_B is not 0 in the same LINQ query and not in a separate LINQ query like the one below i.e. matchRows?

```
var resultsDt = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => new
{
    Id = row.Field<string>("ID")
}).Select(grp =>
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    newRow["ID"] = grp.Key.Id.Trim();
    newRow["PREM_A"] = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("PREM_A"));
    newRow["PREM_B"] = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("PREM_B"));
    return newRow;
}).CopyToDataTable();

var matchRows = resultsDt.Select().Where(x => x.Field<decimal>("PREM_A") != 0 || x.Field<decimal>("PREM_B") != 0);
foreach (DataRow row in matchRows)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Adding a `Where` before call `CopyToDataTable()`. Do you need the result of your query as a datatable?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to a data table for every step, it would be easier to query if you moved away from that.

```
var query =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group new
    {
        premA = row.Field<decimal>("PREM_A"),
        premB = row.Field<decimal>("PREM_B"),
    } by row.Field<string>("ID").Trim() into g
    let premA = g.Sum(x => x.premA)
    let premB = g.Sum(x => x.premB)
    where premA != 0M || premB != 0M
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        PremA = premA,
        PremB = premB,
    };
```

Comment: You could also do lambda syntax by replacing `let` with another `Select`. Why change case of anonymous object property names? Then your final `select` would just list `Id = g.Key, premA, premB`.

Comment: I thought also using `let`, but using it you are not adding two extra selects to the query when is translated?

Comment: @NetMage: In queries such as this, I try to use camel case for all (effectively) local variables and pascal case for externally accessible values in the result as a general rule. Sure it could work without the rename but goes against my own personal code.

Comment: @octavioccl: In the end, it's not going to make much of a difference how it gets translated. Linq in the end of the day is always going to be suboptimal to a raw loop or other approach. So if you're going to use linq, logically it should be efficient, but write it in the form that's maintainable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
 var resultsDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("ID"))                       
                   .Select(grp =>new {Id= grp.Key,
                                     PREM_A= grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("PREM_A")),
                                     PREM_B=grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("PREM_B"))
                                     })
                   .Where(e=>e.PREM_A!=0 || e.PREM_B!=0);
```